# Include/require throughout many different directories PHP

Tags: php, include, require

How do people include or require CSS and JS files throughout their entire application, while keeping the `<head>` tag links valid? How do you create sort of a dynamic file path for meta tags?

**Example:**

I am trying to include header.php with the following content:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Some more 'load first' PHP pieces...
?>
<head>
  <!-- Page titles, some other stuff... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style.css" />
</head>
```

And when I include this in `/index.php` this works. However... As soon as I include it in a file that requires the same header, but that file is inside a directory, the file paths are no longer valid. They should now be like this (notice the "../" before the file paths):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Some more 'load first' PHP pieces...
?>
<head>
  <!-- Page titles, some other stuff... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../path/to/jquery.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../path/to/style.css" />
</head>
```

When I include it in a file that's inside a directory, inside another directory, the file paths should change from `../path/to/file.css` even further to `../../../path/to/file.css`.

Is there a way to include the header file while keeping the external stylesheet and script file paths valid?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? `__DIR__` should be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post to give a better example of what I'm trying to do here...

Comment: Are all css and js files inside one particular directory or each file is in its own directory?

Comment: All files are stored in a sources directory. For example: `src/css` for stylesheets and `src/js` for scripts. I am now checking out `__DIR__` and it seems close to what I need!

Comment: Great. So what happens if you just write `src='/src/js/test.js'`. This can work well if you are developing with a standalone server. In other words, if you are running your project as `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: If I define the path with `/` in front of it, PHP gives me an error: The file cannot be found in XAMPP/htdocs/etc/etc. It's looking from within the XAMPP directory rather than the root of my project.

Comment: Ok, since you are directly using apache server, `__DIR__` would work for development. However, when you make it live, `/src/test.js` being a relative path with respect to the domain name would work just fine

Comment: Many thanks, I found a way to get it to work by placing a `config.php` file in the root directory and write this in it: `define('DIR_ROOT', '/path/to/file.php');` (then include the config file anywhere I need). Perfect! :)